# I am getting a weird behavior from my Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am currently in the U.S and I have a friend in Colombia who is using my RDS. The problem is that whenever we insert a new record into a table, the changes are not reflected  on the other side. For example, if I insert a new record, my friend can't see the change in his SQL developer. The same thing happens when we try the way around, but we still can see our changes. Does this happen because Amazon replicates Data in a weird way?.

Comment: How long did you wait before assuming that the changes are not visible by the other party?

Comment: like 1 min. I still can't see his changes, but I can see my changes.

Comment: Then maybe this is a replication thing here.  One minute strikes me a very long time.

Comment: Is my friend accessing the data from the same data center?

Comment: I don't know.  Are both of you using the exact same connection URL?  This behavior would probably be unsatisfactory to most people, I think.  Also, please include your configuration details, such as what tier you are using (free, paid, etc.).

Comment: I am using an RDS under the free tier. We are using the exact same endpoint and also the same username and password in our sql developer.

Comment: You get what you pay for in life.  My guess here is that free tier does not guarantee lightning fast updates across all of AWS.  That is, if you were using a paid tier, maybe this wouldn't be happening.

Comment: Is there a way my friend can change the zone?

Comment: This has nothing to do with a free tier nor with replication. If there is only one instance there is no replication involved. Did your friend refresh his SQL developer? These tools often do not refresh on their own...

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge is correct, there is no replication and no delay with 1 RDS instance... but this sounds like one or the other of you may simply have a transaction running and not realize it or understand its implications.  Depending in your transaction isolation level, you can't see what another transaction has done and they can't see yours until both of you have committed your changes and have a fresh MVCC view.  If this is the case, the writer needs to `COMMIT` and/or the reader needs to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.  (And if this is the case, it is a programming question, not a server question).

Comment: I am Daniel's friend from Colombia. We just used INSERT INTO statements.